# How to use the printable module with a custom page in Drupal 8

Tags: php, pdf, module, drupal-8

I have a custom page build with a custom path and custom Controller, and I would like to make it printable to download it.

I'm looking at the printable module, but I don't see how to get the path to print it as a pdf file.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Using the controller of the printable module itself, I was able to generate a pdf. You only need to exchange the entity view (compare the showFormat method) with your own render array (build). ConfigFactory is not actually used in this example.

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\your_module\Controller;

use Drupal\Core\Config\ConfigFactory;
use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;
use Drupal\printable\PrintableFormatPluginManager;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;

/**
 * Returns response.
 */
class PrintViewController extends ControllerBase {

  /**
   * The printable format plugin manager.
   *
   * @var \Drupal\printable\PrintableFormatPluginManager
   */
  protected $printableFormatManager;

  /**
   * The configuration factory.
   *
   * @var \Drupal\Core\Config\ConfigFactory
   */
  protected $configFactory;

  /**
   * Constructs a PrintViewController object.
   *
   * @param \Drupal\printable\PrintableFormatPluginManager $printable_format_manager
   *   The printable format plugin manager.
   * @param \Drupal\Core\Config\ConfigFactory $config_factory
   *   The config factory class instance.
   */
  public function __construct(PrintableFormatPluginManager $printable_format_manager, ConfigFactory $config_factory) {
    $this->printableFormatManager = $printable_format_manager;
    $this->configFactory = $config_factory;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public static function create(ContainerInterface $container) {
    return new static(
      $container->get('printable.format_plugin_manager'),
      $container->get('config.factory')
    );
  }

  /**
   * Builds the response.
   */
  public function build() {

    $build['content'] = [
      '#type' => 'item',
      '#markup' => $this->t('It works!'),
    ];

    return $this->showFormat($build, 'pdf'); // One of 'pdf' / 'print'
  }

  /**
   * Returns the entity rendered via the given printable format.
   *
   * @param array $build
   *   The render array be printed.
   * @param string $printable_format
   *   The identifier of the hardcopy format plugin (i.e. print or pdf).
   *
   * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
   *   The printable response.
   */
  public function showFormat(array $build, $printable_format) {
    if (!$this->printableFormatManager->getDefinition($printable_format, FALSE)) {
      throw new NotFoundHttpException();
    }

    $format = $this->printableFormatManager->createInstance($printable_format);
    $format->setContent($build);
    return $format->getResponse();
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to achieve this :

*Use [Entity Print Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_print)*

> Entity Print allows you to print any Drupal entity (Drupal 7 and 8) or
>   View (Drupal 8 only) to PDF.
>
> The module is lightweight compared to other modules like the Print
>   module, has full test coverage and is ready to be used in production
>   for both D7 and D8.

*Use new host of print module ([Printable Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/printable))*

> This is the new home of the print module. The module makes use of
>   pdf_api module to generate PDFs.

Use [PrintFriendly Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/printfriendly) (it supports localization very good)

> The #1 Print and PDF button for your Drupal site. Printer Friendly
>   pages without coding, css, or print.css. Fast, easy, and professional.
>
> The Print Friendly & PDF button saves paper and ink when printing or
>   creating a PDF. It's fast, easy, and looks great when printed. Add the
>   button now, and your users will see the difference.
>
> How Print Friendly & PDF Works The Print Friendly & PDF button
>   automatically creates printer friendly and PDF versions of your pages
>   without the hassle of having to create a print CSS file. No coding,
>   hacking or programming required. Simply install the Print Friendly &
>   PDF plugin, activate, and choose settings for full customization. It
>   also gives your user the ability to remove images and paragraphs of
>   text, so they really only have to print exactly what they want.

Comment: This does not really answer the question, other than listing existing modules and quoting their descriptions. The question is how to make a **custom page** printable. It was as easy in Drupal 7 as putting `print/` before the path using the Print module. On Drupal 8 there is no obvious way.

Comment: @ЕлинЙ. I suggest alternative solutions. instead of aggressive down voting please read what I mentioned there.
I knew print had not worked in D8 so I suggest alternative solutions. keep your down votes for something else !!!

Comment: You don't provide an answer to the question, thus the down vote!  Neither Entity Print nor Printable modules are capable of printing custom created pages (using routing and controllers). The third module is a third party service. If you know better, then explain how to do it, so that I can count it as an answer.

Comment: @ЕлинЙ. 2 years ago. I'm pretty sure those module are working

Comment: Don't you understand? Those modules *ARE NOT CAPABLE OF PRINTING **CUSTOM CREATED PAGES** *.

Comment: @ЕлинЙ. have you tested it?

Comment: I wouldn't comment, if I haven't tested. Have you tested them?

Comment: @ЕлинЙ., not now but a long time ago I could be able to print custom views page by these modules. I haven't tried them with a fully custom page. but if you want I help you with the custom page please create a question with your custom page code. I will definitely be happy to help you. create a question and give the link to me.